# How to compile this hello world OS?

Tags: c, operating-system, boot

I am trying to experiment with the [helloWorld OS](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigops/roll_your_own/1.helloworld.html). I followed the instructions given but cannot make `main.c`. I looked in the make file and it refrences `./bootmaker` which is not in the folder they say to download. It looks as if it's a script that they ran but I do not know how to get it or create it. Where can I get `./bootmaker` or are there programs that will do the same job as it that I can use instead?

**Update**
I'd like to add that this was a classic case of not fully reading the documentation provided to me which caused my confusion and I apollogize for the bad post.

Comment: Have you tried reading the page you linked and the pages it links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4th step in that guide gives you a link to Bootmaker.

This is the link: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigops/roll_your_own/1.bootstrap.html

Bootmaker sources: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigops/roll_your_own/code/util.tar.gz